# android : non zero exit value 2 after Use Google Analytics

Tags: android, gradle

why after i compile the `Google Analytics`'s library on `gradle`, i got an error `non zero exit value 2`

i have been looking for the solution in much website on stackoverflow's member, but still error.

This is my gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.userName.googleanalytic"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.3.0'

}
```

i just follow this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2015/08/android-integrating-google-analytics-v4/

please help me, to solve this issue.

Comment: use multiDexEnabled true after versionName "1.0" in defaultConfig and use library version always below or equal to build tools version.

Comment: None of those two suggestions apply here @Brendon

Comment: yes @Daniel is right, i have tried all those solution, but i got nothing.

Comment: Can you maybe add some extra info about your error? When does it happen exactly?

Comment: @RBesar do u have anything under libs folder? add some extra details, so that the issue will be caught and will solve it

Comment: @Brendon Do not use `multiDexEnabled` if you do not need to. That dramatically slows down builds. This user has very few dependencies.

Comment: @RBesar Post all of your code. Please use latest `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'`.

Comment: @JaredBurrows i didnt force the user to use multidex, i just suggested it may work, there is no detail code to help.

Comment: @Brendon, that's right, i have file jar under libs folder. i have removed it, and build the program again. it works! thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @friends, thank you guys for your comment, i appreciate it. the problem is i have file jar under libs folder.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem (suggestion from member that comment under my post) :

the problem is, i have 2 same library in difference place:
1. file `libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar`under libs folder.
2. i put `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.3.0'` in gradle.

program confused to execute because there are two same library in one project.

it caused error `non zero exit value 2` (in my case*)

solution :

- just remove the jar file (in my case i remove `libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar`).
- clean and build again
- trust me it works! (*if your problem equals to me*)

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line `compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')`

and compile .jar files separately,

If you have .jar file related to google-play-services then remove that jar also, since the gradle `com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.3.0` is enough to load the library, otherwise it will compile redundant library and will throw exceptions as duplicate.